# How to disable translated search results

Tags: google-search, localization, translation

Today, suddenly messed-up "translated" results like these started appearing which apparently were auto-translated from English to German:

[image]

It seems to be [this auto-translation feature](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/translated-results). Unfortunately, the linked article only explains how *websites* can prevent being auto-translated, not how *users* can turn that feature off.

I already checked my Google search preferences and both German and English are set as preferred search result languages. I googled this problem and only found the suggestion to switch my display language (which I don't want and also it would probably just cause the opposite problem, with German results getting auto-translated to English next time) as well as the suggestion to disable the "offer to translate pages" setting in Chrome's settings (which I don't want to disable either, actually, but I tried it, and disabling that didn't change anything).

What can I do? This is really irritating!

Comment: I found this because I'm in the exact same situation. Incredibly annoying. Automatic translations that can't be turned off have been a widely known problem on Youtube for quite a few years, but instead of fixing it there, they now decided to f* up my search results. Even worse, if I click a search result without clicking "view original" first, Google even takes me to a fully auto-translated page instead of the original search result. They really think I don't know a word of English even though it's right there in my account settings. What's that setting even for if they just ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real solution, but a workaround I came up with for now: I created a Userscript as follows:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Untranslate
// @namespace    https://david-trapp.com/
// @version      2023-12-14
// @description  Auto-show original of translated search results
// @author       David Trapp
// @match        https://www.google.com/search?*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=google.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict'

    function untranslate () {
        [...document.querySelectorAll('svg[viewBox="0 0 24 24"]')]
            .reverse()
            .map(x => x.closest('[data-ved]')?.querySelector('[jsaction]'))
            .filter(x => x?.innerText.includes('Original ansehen') && !x?.classList.contains('untranslated') && x?.closest('[jscontroller]'))
            .forEach(x => {
                x.closest('[jscontroller]').style.display = 'none' // Prevent scroll on .focus() and get rid of the translation box entirely
                x.classList.add('untranslated')
                x.click()
            })
    }

    untranslate()
    new MutationObserver(untranslate).observe(document.body, { subtree: true, childList: true })
})()
```

Note that the text `Original ansehen` needs to be changed based on what language the results are translated to.